# EF Core create a new independent transaction inside a transaction

Tags: transactions, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

In my code I need to perform an operation in the database and commit it while another (ambient) transaction is already in place (imagine an audit trail, but this is just an example). This of course must be carried in a separate connection, but I don't know how to force EF to use a new connection for the dbcontext.

While doing some work on the database for which I have a `dbContext` and an existing transaction, I need to call some procedure to make immediate permanent changes in the database. In this procedure I can call `serviceProvider.CreateScope()` to create new scope, grab a `newDbContext` and a use `newDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()` there, but it turns out that the new transaction is just nested inside the outer transaction; if the outer transaction rolls back, changes made in `newDbContext` are lost, but I want my changes to persist even if the outer transaction fails.

How can I run a separate transaction within my code flow that is independent from the ambient transaction? I tried `new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)` but it fails with *"The ambient transaction needs to be completed before beginning a transaction on this connection."*

**EDIT**: clarified about using a new connection for the separate transaction.

Comment: SQL Server itself has no support for this, so it's not like EF can do much there. The only way to do this is to open a brand new connection (not merely a scope, not merely a context) and perform the transaction plus statements there, but I'm not sure you can control connection management that precisely from within EF (I have little practical experience with EF).

Comment: SQL Server should support it if I use a separate connection. The thing is that I don't know how to force EF Core to use a separate connection.

Comment: A `DbContext` accepts a `DbConnection` on construction, so as long as you can grab the connection string from somewhere you can create a new context on its own connection. It should be available through `DbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString`; the cleanest way of creating a new connection would then be using the connection's `ConnectionProvider` and `CreateConnection`. Disclaimer: I have no idea if this is the "right" way to do it from the POV of EF.

Comment: The problem is that I'm getting the dbcontext from dependency injection, so I have no control on the constructor parameters used for creating it. Maybe I could create it manually for this process in particular, though. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It should be possible (though not necessarily trivial if you're heavily relying on defaults) to customize the dependency injection to give you access to a way of creating a new `DbContext` specifically for auditing, based on the existing `DbContext`s it hands out. This would cleanly signal your intent to get an independent context (which would even allow you to split off auditing to a separate DB if it were so desired). Of course auditing was just an example, so if you needed this in a generic way the approach would look slightly different (an extension method on `DbContext` would work).